# How to drag item out of horizontal scroll container?

Tags: css, drag-and-drop, overflow, interact.js

I have a container that has overflow:auto so that it scroll's horizontally. I want to be able to drag an item out of that container to an above div. For this I have either been changing the container to overflow visible, or the items to have absolute positioning onClick. Both have resulted in some unsavory results when I scroll sideways and then start dragging an element (using interact.js), the xposition of the scroll is added to the item's place on the screen. This causes it to jump far right, what is the best way to approach this issue?

Comment: Can you share some code or JS fiddle of what you're trying to do? That way the question will be more clear.

Comment: ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

`touch-action: pan-x;` on a draggable element.